# Would an Ember component be the right way to do this?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to randomly show 1 of 5 elements.

If I had the following:

```
<div class='random-houses'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/1.png" data-number='1'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/2.png" data-number='2'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/3.png" data-number='3'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/4.png" data-number='4'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/5.png" data-number='5'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/6.png" data-number='6'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/7.png" data-number='7'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/8.png" data-number='8'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/9.png" data-number='9'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/10.png" data-number='10'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/11.png" data-number='11'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/12.png" data-number='12'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/13.png" data-number='13'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/14.png" data-number='14'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/15.png" data-number='15'>
  <img src="/assets/images/houses/16.png" data-number='16'>
</div>
```

How would I randomly select one of these to be visible with ember components? Do I just wrap it in a `didInsertElement` block for the logic or is there a more elegant way to do it? I'd really appreciate a working example. Thank you :)

Here's how I did it for now:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['random-house'],
  attributeBindings: ['style'],
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    $("[data-number='" + number + "']").show();
  }
});
```

Would there be a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had shoulder surgery, so i can't type a ton /only have one hand.  so it's a little ugly and raw, but it should get you started.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oBunoFOH/1/edit